# How do i make a simple word counter in javascript and display it to a <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
function countWords(){
    var sentence = document.getElementById("sentence-input").value;

    var text = sentence.split(" ");

    var lengthofString = text.length;

    document.getElementsByClassName("word-count").innerText = lengthofString;

    console.log(text);
    console.log("length of string " + lengthofString);

}
```

Here is my current code, I'm able to get the length of the current string but i dont know how to simply display that number in my paragraph element.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns collection, use index `document.getElementsByClassName("word-count")[0].innerText = lengthofString;`

Comment: I suggest `document.querySelector(".word-count").innerText = lengthofString;`  - it makes more sense when there is only one element, or use an ID there too

Comment: Thank you guys i tried your suggestions and was able to figure it out!